# C# GET REST xml to object deserialization encoding clash

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, encoding, uwp

I wanna get xml file from http and convert it to object.
So right now I have 2 methods: one to get http response body like that:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var op = httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
var httpResponseBody = "";
try {
    var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    httpResponseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return httpResponseBody;
    }
    ...
```

which returns string httpResponseBody.
Second one tries to convert this xml in string to object:

```
res = await task;
var reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Schedule));
using (var tr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(res)))
{
  var schedule = (Schedule)reader.Deserialize(tr);
  return schedule;
}
```

The problem is that the content I receive is in different encoding and I don't know how to convert it to make deserialization possible.

I am getting something like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<ramowka><dzien name=\"PoniedziaÅ\u0082ek\" count=\"2\"/></ramowka>\n
```

How to get rid of '\n' and Å\u0082 (should be ł) ?
Right now I am getting Exception from `reader.Deserialize`: `{"<ramowka xmlns=''> was not expected."}`

Schedule class:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Schedule
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("ramowka")]
    public ScheduleDay[] AuditionDays { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does the `Schedule` class look like?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the root object on the `XmlSerializer` fixes the problem:

```
var reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Schedule), new XmlRootAttribute("ramowka"));
```

...though I used slightly different attributes:

```
[DataContract]
public class ScheduleDay
{
    [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember, XmlAttribute]
    public string count { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Schedule
{
    [DataMember]
    public ScheduleDay dzien { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't tried yours yet, but these work.

---

For a collection of `ScheduleDay`s, this combo works:

```
[XmlType("dzien")]
public class ScheduleDay
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string count { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ScheduleDay>), new XmlRootAttribute("ramowka"));
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Xml)))
{
    List<ScheduleDay> schedule = (List<ScheduleDay>)reader.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

The `Schedule` class just disappeared from the equation.

---

### Escapes in the HTML

The `\n`s are part of the XML structure, so no need to worry about those. The deserializer will translate `\u0082` into its equivalent character, which is
[BREAK PERMITTED HERE](https://codepoints.net/U+0082?lang=en). Which you probably don't want. The `Å` looks out of place too -- it's the last letter of the Norwegian alphabet and not used in Polish, AFAIK.

Comment: I've gave only example but there is more <dzien> tags in <ramowka>. How to handle it than?

Answer (score 1):

I've changed Schedule class to:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRootAttribute("ramowka")]
public class Schedule
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("dzien")]
    public ScheduleDay[] AuditionDays { get; set; }
}
```

Now it looks like working. Thanks Petter for hint with Root attribute.